# How to change Paypal Billing Plans to CREATED state from ACTIVE state?

Tags: php, paypal, billing, paypal-rest-sdk

I have already made 3 separate Billing Plans and updated them to **ACTIVE** state. There aren't any agreements associated with it yet.

I wanted to be able to edit the details of a plan after they've been switched to ACTIVE state.

So, when I tried to update the plan, it gave me an error saying:

```
{"name":"BUSINESS_VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"validation_error","issue":"Requested state change is invalid."}]
```

So, I tried to convert the state to **CREATED** again, so I can edit the details. Here's the code snippet I tried:

```
try {

         $statePatch = new PayPal\Api\Patch();
         $statePatch->setOp('replace')
           ->setPath('/')
           ->setValue(array('state' => 'CREATED'));
         $statePatchRequest = new \PayPal\Api\PatchRequest();
         $statePatchRequest->addPatch($statePatch);
         $plan->update($statePatchRequest, $apiContext);
         $updatedPlan = \PayPal\Api\Plan::get($plan->getId(), $apiContext);

      } catch (Exception $ex) {
         var_dump($ex);
         exit(1);
      }
```

But that still didn't work. The API again gave a similar error.

```
private 'url' => string 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/P-6DK979342A210870GWHVJFGY' (length=83)
  private 'data' => string '{"name":"BUSINESS_VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"validation_error","issue":"Requested state change is invalid."}],"message":"Validation Error.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#BUSINESS_VALIDATION_ERROR","debug_id":"5cf8ac1da4fa8"}' (length=283)
  protected 'message' => string 'Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/P-6DK979342A210870GWHVJFGY.' (length=126)
  private 'string' (Exception) => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'code' => int 400
  protected 'file' => string '/var/www/public/application/third_party/PayPal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php' (length=119)
  protected 'line' => int 177
```

I can't find any references anywhere on how to do this. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to follow the [samples](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/) provided in the [PayPal REST API SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) directly.

http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/billing/UpdatePlan.html

From the look of it, you need the "state" to be **ACTIVE**, and not **CREATED**

Comment: Patel: I think you misunderstood my question... I was trying to **edit** the plan description while it was already in the **ACTIVE** state. I couldn't do it. That why, I tried putting it back to **CREATED** state, thought I would be able to edit it then. Is there any way to **edit** the Plan details?

Comment: Oh ! Now I get it. Unfortunately, once the plan has activated, it cannot be edited, because it could affect the already signed agreements to change. However, API team has realized this issue, and is trying to see if we could update few components of plan to be edited.

Comment: That's music to my ears. :) It'd be great if we could edit the description and the amount.

But, for the time being, if we decide to discontinue a certain plan afterwards, or create a new one to increase the amount, in that case,   how are we supposed to manage the billing agreements (and find its related plan data) ?

Also, this present with another problem, how do we *migrate* the users to the new plan, if it is meant as a replacement to the older plan?